# How avoid 'If cascade' and type casting by using polymorphism?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, polymorphism

Let's assume the following class structure with base class BC and 2 derived classes DC_A and DC_B;
Furthermore there is a class XY with a methode goo() with a parameter of type BC and other methodes

```
// base class
public class BC
{
    public virtual void foo();
}

// derived class A
public class DC_A : BC
{
    public override void  foo() {}
}

// derived class B
public class DC_B : BC
{
    public override void  foo() {}
}


public class XY
{
    public void goo(BC o)
    {
        // perfectly fine using polymorphism; no Ifs' no casting, OOP at its best ;-)
        o.foo();

        // but what to do here?
        if ( (o as DC_A) != null )
        {
            doX(o as DC_A);
        }
        else if ((o as DC_B) != null)
        {
            doY(o as DC_B);
        }
    }

    private void doX(DC_A o) {}
    private void doY(DC_B o) {}
}
```

In '[Is passing around value objects using polymorphism a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202561/is-passing-around-value-objects-using-polymorphism-a-bad-practice)' the Visitor pattern is proposed;

The problem of the If cascade and the casting is moved (not eliminated) into the abstract base class.

Are there better solutions to completely avoid the if's?

Its no option for me (in this example) to move the functionality from doX/doY to class DC_A/DC_B

Your advice is much appreciated.

Edit:
The background of this question is a C# / WinForms application with a form to manage a "test rule" consisting of differenct sub entities like TestSpec with a collection of measurement types, test limits, and so on (my DC_A, DC_B classes) all derived from EntityBase (=BC from above)
The form sends an event to the controller that a sub entity has changed;
  simplified PropertiesChanged(EntityBase o)
The controller calls the corresponding methode in the model class (methode goo in class XY from above) which is now responsible to do the businesslogic which is not only persisting the changed sub entity test limit but also e.g. creating a new test limit revision object, increasing a test spec revision, etc..
Maybe in this way 
the generic approach of having a methode like PropertiesChanged(EntityBase o) should be changed to more specifing events from the form and specific event handler in controller and model class to handle  "TestLimitChanged" etc.

But this special case has led me to the more generic or "philosophical" question about polymorphism at all ;-)

Comment: If DoX and DoY work very differently but should be logically called at the same point, the only thing wrong with your approach is that you should delegate the responsibility of chosing which to use elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using .NET 4 there is a possibility with overloading and dynamic type, maybe that is an alternativ for you.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DC_A dca = new DC_A();
        DC_B dcb = new DC_B();
        XY xy = new XY();
        xy.goo(dca);
        xy.goo(dcb);
    }
}

// base class
public abstract class BC
{
    public abstract void foo();
}

// derived class A
public class DC_A : BC
{
    public override void foo() { }
}

// derived class B
public class DC_B : BC
{
    public override void foo() { }
}


public class XY
{
    //public void goo<T>(T o) where T : BC
    //{
    //    //dynamic dyn = Convert.ChangeType(o, o.GetType());
    //    //dynamic dyn = o;
    //    //gooi(dyn);
    //    gooi((dynamic)o);
    //}

    // http://smellegantcode.wordpress.com/2008/11/04/dynamic-typing-in-c-4-and-duck-generics/
    public void goo<T>(T o) where T : BC
    {
        gooi((dynamic)o);
    }

    private void gooi(DC_A o)
    {
        o.foo();
        doX(o);
    }

    private void gooi(DC_B o)
    {
        o.foo();
        doY(o);
    }

    private void gooi(BC o)
    {
        o.foo();
    }

    private void doX(DC_A o) { }
    private void doY(DC_B o) { }
}
```

Comment: To speed up the code replace "dynamic dyn = Convert.ChangeType(o, o.GetType());" with "dynamic dyn = o;"

Comment: Thats what I wanted to do, perfect!
With the little help of .NET (dynamic types) and OOP (overloading), no more if's and casts necessary. Thanks for this solution

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion:

1. Expose your doX() and doY() methods so they can be called from implementations of DC_A and DC_B.
2. Add an abstract Do() method to BC.
3. Implement Do() in DC_A to call the exposed doX() method.
4. Implement Do() in DC_B to call the exposed doY() method.
5. Inside goo(), just call o.Do().

You could decouple things further by passing a delegate to DC_A and DC_B which they will call, instead of exposing doX() and doY(). It very much depends on the usage patterns.

However, this is only really very useful if you can add some value to the Do() implementations in the derived classes. If all Do() does is just call doX() or doY(), you don't really get any benefit from doing it this way.

So I'm going to agree with the other poster here that says just do the casting.

Comment: Many thanks for your proposal; but to complicate some things..
What if doX/doY would not only depend on the object DC itself but also on other parameters, etc. which BC (DC_A, DC_B) cant (should) not know?    
e.g. doX(o as DC_A,  otherPara1, otherPara2, DBconnectionPara3..)?

Comment: In that case, I think you need to consider what it is that doX() and doY() is actually doing. What are the extra bits of DC_A and DC_B that they are using? It's difficult to tell from a generalised example such as the one in this thread. For example, what do you want to happen if someone else creates a DC_C class, and passes that in? How will you ensure that the implementer of DC_C knows they should be doing something in class XY as well? Can you provide any more details? But if it's too complicated, you might as well just do what you're already.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's too much to worry about, once we fix a couple of things:

- At the moment you're casting more than you need to
- Only one of those `if`s can be true, so you don't need an `else`

After that, we have:

```
    // perfectly fine using polymorphism; no Ifs' no casting, OOP at its best ;-)
    o.foo();

    var dca = o as DC_A;
    if (dca != null)
    {
        doX(dca);
    }

    var dcb = o as DC_B;
    if (dcb != null)
    {
        doY(dcb);
    }
```

which I'd say looks fine.

If you want to go further, you could change the implementations of `doX` and `doY` so that they return immediately if passed `null`; then you could just say

```
doX(o as DC_A);
doY(o as DC_B);
```

Comment: You are right; calling doX(o as DC_A) and checking for NULL pointers within doX would be an approach;
It moves the casting into the fucntion call and the IF-check into doX avoiding the nasty if-then-else cascade;
But it does not avoid the ifs and casting.